# JmsCorrelationId for async messaging send

Tags: java, jms

Are there any set norms for what a JMSCorrId should  be set to. My application is simply sending a message async to a queue and it doesn't care about waiting for any acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

When the JMS client receives the reply message, it can match the JMSCorrelationID of the new message with the corresponding JMSMessageID of the message it sent, so that it knows which message received a reply.

The JMSCorrelationID can be any value, not just a JMSMessageID.

For example you can use JMSCorrelationID to identify the sender.

If you decide to use your own ID, be aware that you should not start an application-specific JMSCorrelationID with ID:. That prefix is reserved for IDs generated by JMS providers.

Typically implementation:

```
public void onMessage(Message message){
try {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)message;
        Queue replyQueue = (Queue)textMessage.getJMSReplyTo();

        Message replyMessage = session.createMessage();
        replyMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSMessageID());
        sender.send(replyQueue, replyMessage);
    } catch (JMSException jmse){jmse.printStackTrace();}
}
```